# how to get column count

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

i have a query like below

```
select project_task_id,
       status_id,
       sum(case when StatusID=1 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=1,
       sum(case whenStatusID=2 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=2,
       sum(case when StatusID=3 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=3,
       sum(case when StatusID=4 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=4,
       sum(case when StatusID=5 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=5,
       sum(case when StatusID=6 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=6,
       sum(case when StatusID=7 then 1 else 0 end) as task_id=7,
from"Projects".work_unit_status 
group by project_task_id,status_id;
```

I'm getting the below attached output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wfD1.png

and I want to get the below expected output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zql9z.png

include zero's if the status_id is blank
please any one help on this

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use the addition of all sum column

```
 select project_task_id,status_id,
isnull(sum(case when StatusID=1 then 1 else 0 end),0)+
isnull(sum(case whenStatusID=2 then 1 else 0 end),0) +
isnullsum(case when StatusID=3 then 1 else 0 end),0) +
isnullsum(case when StatusID=4 then 1 else 0 end),0)+
isnullsum(case when StatusID=5 then 1 else 0 end),0) +
isnullsum(case when StatusID=6 then 1 else 0 end),0) +
isnullsum(case when StatusID=7 then 1 else 0 end),0) as count_status
from"Projects".work_unit_status group by project_task_id,status_id
```

Comment: need to include zero if the filed is empty

Comment: when the field is empty it will automatically be ignored. why you need 0 then ?

Comment: ERROR:  function isnull(bigint, integer) does not exist
LINE 6: isnull(sum(case when status_id=1 then 1 else 0 end),0)+
        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function isnull(bigint, integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 45

getting above error  while running

Comment: i want to display the output like that only please help me

Answer (score 0):

use `in` with your case

```
with t1 as (
 select project_task_id,
           status_id,
           sum(case when StatusID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) then 1 else 0) 
           as sum_s               
    from "Projects".work_unit_status

    group by project_task_id,status_id
              ) ,
           t2 as
             (
                 select * from (
                 select 1 as statusid 
                          union
                 select 2
                 union 
                 select 3
                 union
                 select 4 
                 union
                 select 5 
                 union
                 select 6
                  union
                select 7 ) t
             ) select t1.project_task_id,
                   t2.statusid,
                    case when t1.sum_s>0 or not null
                    then sum_s else 0 end as total
                  t2 full join t1 on t2.statusid=t1.status_id
```

Comment: how to include zero's if statusid is blank please help me

Comment: @narsimha use another case when statusid is null then 0

Comment: @narsimha check i edited answer btw how you want to show blank statusid ? do you want sum of those or else

Comment: i want to include '0'(zero) if the statusid blank for example for project_task_id is 4 have only status id is 2 .remaining i want to display as 0

Comment: @narsimha could you please add your sample table data

Comment: i want to include '0'(zero) if the statusid blank for example for project_task_id is 4 have only status id is 2 .remaining i want to display as 0 "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zql9z.png" please open this clearly visible thanks inadvance

Comment: @narsimha i change my query look now and btw it will works it your for 1to 7 statusid

Comment: please let me now am getting below error "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t2"
LINE 30: t2 left join cte on t2.status_id=t1.status_id
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "t2"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 698

near .......case when cte.sum_s>0 then sum_s else 0 end as total 
t2 left join cte on t2.status_id=t1.status_id

Comment: @i edited answer again but its tough as you don share your table data but it seems my query is fine

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact table structure I assumed that status_id and statusId refer to the same column. (If they are different columns, we need to use StatusId in the COUNT.)

Based on the expected output, you want to count the status_id and group by project_task_id. To make sure that every status is represented for every task, first, we need to create a subquery of all possible project_task_id/status_id combinations. Then we use that with the aggregate values of the original table.

```
select
  ps.project_task_id,
  ps.status_id,
  count(w.status_id) as total
from (
  select distinct
      project_task_id,
      s.status_id
  from work_unit_status
  cross join (select distinct status_id from work_unit_status) s
  ) ps
left join work_unit_status w
    on ps.project_task_id = w.project_task_id and ps.status_id = w.status_id 
group by
    ps.project_task_id,
    ps.status_id
```

If you really need to hardcode the statuses from 1 to 7, use the query below.

```
select
  ps.project_task_id,
  ps.status_id,
  count(w.status_id) as total
from (
  select distinct
      project_task_id,
      s.status_id
  from work_unit_status
    cross join (
          select 1 as status_id
    union select 2
    union select 3
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    ) s
  ) ps
left join work_unit_status w
  on ps.project_task_id = w.project_task_id and ps.status_id = w.status_id 
group by
  ps.project_task_id,
  ps.status_id
order by
  ps.project_task_id,
  ps.status_id
```

Comment: need to include status_id "1 to 7" if the status_id is blank need to get total 0

Comment: Have you tried it? It gives back 0 when the status_id is blank. If you have status_id that doesn't exist in your table at all, that won't be visible. In that case, the simplest way is to join your table with the status table (where the status_id is the primary key).